# How to query a MongoDB over two collections

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, uuid, bson

I have two collections **LockQueue** and **MessageClassification**. The MessageClassification _id is stored as UUID string in the LockQueue. The MessageEventId that is stored in the MessageClassification is the entry into the search query. I need a value from the LockQueue collection. Running the queries separably in Studio 3T:

```
db.getCollection("MessageClassification").find({'Message.EventId': 'ESI00008'})
db.getCollection("LockQueue").find({"Data.ClassificationId": CSUUID("EDDF6494-D4BB-48C2-A08E-D61F31313826")})
```

Yield the expected result. Now I would like to automate that with Python.

By searching the internet for a day I came to the following query. When I run it it does not give an error, it also does not end without a result. It looks like somewhere it has gone into a never ending loop, or is very slow. Cntrl+C doesn't stop the query.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import uuid

uri = "mongodb://user:password@server.intern:27017/DB?serverSelectionTimeoutMS=5000&connectTimeoutMS=10000&authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1"

client = MongoClient(uri, uuidRepresentation='csharpLegacy')


mydatabase = client["DB"]

coll = mydatabase["LockQueue"]

cursor = [{'$lookup': {
             'from': 'MessageClassification',
             'let': {'id': {'$toString': '$_id'}},
             'pipeline': [
               {
                 '$match': {
                   '$expr': {
                     '$and': [
                       {'$eq': ['$$id', '$Data.ClassificationId']},
                       {'$eq': ['$Message.EventId', 'ESI00008']}
                     ]                       
                    }
                  }
                }
             ],
             'as': 'message'
           }
         }]
           
for doc in (coll.aggregate(cursor)):
    print(doc)
```

What is it that I'm missing?

**Added:**
The connection string is the same as used in Studio 3T.

Comment: What happens if you use, `client = MongoClient(uri, uuidRepresentation=UuidRepresentation.CSHARP_LEGACY)`?

Comment: Assuming that the connection stuff is correct or gets sorted out per @rickhg12s guidance above,  we need to improve the performance of this operation. You should prepend a `$match` stage to the beginning of the pipeline that applies the correct filter to the base collection. You should also make sure you have an index on the `from` collection on the field(s) being joined on